# How do I write a sequence of promises in Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlinx.coroutines

Is it possible to write a sequence of [promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) (or tasks) using **only** Kotlin?

For example, a sequence promises in JavaScript is written as:

```
const SLEEP_INTERVAL_IN_MILLISECONDS = 200;

const alpha = function alpha (number) {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        const fulfill = function() {
            return resolve(number + 1);
        };

        return setTimeout(fulfill, SLEEP_INTERVAL_IN_MILLISECONDS);
    });
};

const bravo = function bravo (number) {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        const fulfill = function() {
            return resolve(Math.ceil(1000*Math.random()) + number);
        };
        return setTimeout(fulfill, SLEEP_INTERVAL_IN_MILLISECONDS);
    });
};

const charlie = function charlie (number) {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        return (number%2 == 0) ? reject(number) : resolve(number);
    });
};

function run() {
    return Promise.resolve(42)
        .then(alpha)
        .then(bravo)
        .then(charlie)
        .then((number) => {
            console.log('success: ' + number)
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.log('error: ' + error);
        });
}

run();
```

Each function [also returns a Promise](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/getting-started/primers/promises) with asynchronous processing result, that would be resolved/rejected by the immediately following promise.

I know how to write this using[RxKotlin](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxKotlin), but I am trying to figure out how to write it using [coroutines library](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/coroutines-overview.html) or any other standard feature.

Answer (score 5):

As you mentioned, [coroutines](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/coroutines-overview.html) are the standard feature to go with.

You have to use the `suspend` keyword, if the function will be suspended, e.g. IO, or if you call another `suspend` function, e.g. `delay`.

The error handling can be done with the normal `try-catch` statement.

```
import kotlinx.coroutines.delay
import java.lang.Exception
import kotlin.math.ceil

const val SLEEP_INTERVAL_IN_MILLISECONDS = 200

suspend fun alpha(number: Int): Int {
    delay(SLEEP_INTERVAL_IN_MILLISECONDS)
    return number + 1
}

suspend fun bravo(number: Int): Int {
    delay(SLEEP_INTERVAL_IN_MILLISECONDS)
    return ceil(1000 * Math.random() + number).toInt()
}

fun charlie(number: Int): Int =
    number.takeIf { it % 2 == 0 } ?: throw IllegalStateException(number.toString())

suspend fun run() {
    try {
        val result = charlie(bravo(alpha(42)))
        println(result)
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        println(e)
    }
}

suspend fun main() {
    run()
}
```

If you like a more functional style for error handling, you can go with this:

```
suspend fun run() {
    runCatching { charlie(bravo(alpha(42))) }
        .onFailure { println(it) }
        .onSuccess { println(it) }
}
```